# Why Role Rights Are Not Assigned to a User?

Tags: django

Why when I create a user and assign a role to him the role rights are not assigned?

`self.request.user.get_user_permissions()` returns empty tuple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're using the wrong function.

That function [is documented to](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.get_user_permissions) only return the set of permission strings that the user has directly.

Use [`get_all_permissions(obj=None)`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.get_all_permissions):

> Returns a set of permission strings that the user has, both through group and user permissions.
>
> If `obj` is passed in, only returns the permissions for this specific object.